# Need MySql query that should return result by ordering values in particular field

Tags: mysql

Need MySql query that should return result by ordering values in particular field.

From below my result set should contain order like parent_id (1,4,6) should come first parent_id(2,3,7) come next and other should come last.

```
d  data  parent_id
----------------------
1      a1       1
2      abc      3
3      abcd     4
4      xyz      2
5      zxyy     6
2      abc      8
3      abcd     9
4      xyz      2
5      zxyy     15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT d, data, parent_id
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN parent_id IN (1, 4, 6) THEN 1
              WHEN parent_id IN (2, 3, 7) THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END,
         parent_id
```

Follow the link below for a running demo:

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use below mentioned query

```
SELECT d, data, parent_id FROM table_name ORDER BY FIELD(parent_id,1,4,6,2,3,7);
```